# Having difficulty defining Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to create a new route to perform an action.

Currently I have the following defined in my routes

```
match 'books/scrape_data' => 'books#scrape_data', :via => :get
```

and the following action

```
def scrape_data
  @books = Book.all
  @books.each do |book|
#    do stuff
  end
  redirect_to :action => 'list'
end
```

But the route seems to go to the show action with :id 'scrape_data'.

Can anyone point my in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you must also have a route definition such as `resources :books` that appears before the route you listed in your question. Since routes are parsed top-down, the books#show route is intercepting your route and bucketing `scrape_data` into the id. Run `bundle exec rake routes` to see the order of the routes defined.

The easy fix is to move your route up above `resources :books`. But it'd actually be more correct to get rid of your custom route and add it to the resources block like this:

```
resources :books do
  get 'scrape_data', on: :collection
end
```

After this, do another `bundle exec rake routes` and see if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the "answer", but I don't have the rep to comment.

My go to resource for all things routing related is [Routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Run `bundle exec rake routes` to see your routes and how they're nested. Then you'll see whether your params are matching up (common mistake with nested routes).

Answer (score 0):

You can also view all of your routes by going to:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes
```

which can be pretty helpful instead of having to kill your server and use the console.